# How should a controller be specified in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller

Assume we have these 2 snippets, what's the difference between `controller: function (...) { }` and `controller: 'myController'`

```
app.directive('testDirective', function () {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function() {
           // Do something
      },
      link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, controller) {     
          // Do something
      });
   }
});
```

Alternative

```
app.directive('testDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'myController',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attributes, controller) {     
          // Do something
      });
   }
});

app.controller('myController', function () { });
```

Is there any benefit between the two methods?

I have a suspicion that dependency injection does not work properly on the first case, specifically when unit-testing. Is that right or not?

Comment: At runtime, it makes no difference. In tests, the second one allows testing the controller easily: you don't even have to know or care that it's used by a directive. It's just a regular controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have noticed exactly what you said, that testing is easier.

Comment: Also you can do dependency injection in both cases using either [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) or [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation)